# Targeting elements with dynamically created id tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have tried troubleshooting this by referring to a range of other SO topics but have so far come up empty. I am trying to target individual elements with dynamically created (via an AJAX GET request) id tags, so I can operate on that individual element.

When I click on one of the relevant buttons, currently my console.log check is returning:

`Clicked undefined`

Here is the AJAX call

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/electra/get_users/',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {        
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var myCol = $('<div id="col" class="col-sm-4"></div>');
                var myPanel = $(
                    '<div class="card-group"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">'+data[i]+'</h5><p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p><button class="card-btn" id=' + data[i] + 'FollowButton>Follow</button><button class="card-btn" id=' + data[i]+ 'ViewDashButton>View Dashboard</button></div></div></div>'
                    );
                myPanel.appendTo(myCol);
                myCol.appendTo('#contentPanel');

                document.querySelector("#" + data[i] + "FollowButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var tag = data[i];
                    console.log("Clicked" + " " + tag);
                });
            };      
        };              
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question, but I'd suggest you to learn about [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle your scenario, instead of assigning an event listener to each item.

Comment: To answer your specific question of why you get `undefined` - your `i` loop value is global, so by the time it gets to `var tag = data[i]` it's no longer the value it was when you setup the div/event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/electra/get_users/',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {        
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var myCol = $('<div id="col" class="col-sm-4"></div>');
            var myPanel = $(
                '<div class="card-group"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">'+data[i]+'</h5><p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p><button class="card-btn" data-idtext='+ data[i]+' id=' + data[i] + 'FollowButton>Follow</button><button class="card-btn" id=' + data[i]+ 'ViewDashButton>View Dashboard</button></div></div></div>'
                );
            myPanel.appendTo(myCol);
            myCol.appendTo('#contentPanel');

            document.querySelector("#" + data[i] + "FollowButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
                var tag = $(this).data('idtext');
                console.log("Clicked" + " " + tag);
            });
        };      
    };              
});
```

Comment: You can add data[i] value as a attribute and use it at the time of clicking button

Comment: Like data-idtext='+ data[i]+' for the follow button